# Program can't compare Chars (C)

Tags: c, if-statement, char, scanf

A function in my program is not executing the if statement and I'm not sure why. I checked if \n was a factor but it wasn't. Is this not the proper way to check if a char is a certain value?

```c
void kitColour() {

    printf("Enter the kit colour: ");
    scanf("%s", &database[currentStorage].colours);

    char *inputColour = database[currentStorage].colours;

    printf("%s", inputColour);

    // check if ROYGBIV
    if (inputColour == 'R') {

        printf("letter is R");
    }

    // skips previous if statement and executes this one
    if (strlen(inputColour) == 1) {

        currentStorage++;
        mainMenu();
    }

    printf("Only the values 'R', 'O', 'Y', 'G', 'B', 'I', 'V' are acceptable.\n");
    kitColour();
}
```

I tried to compare the user input to the value 'R' but it does not execute the if statement. I expected it to print "letter is R". Instead it skips the if statement and continues with the program.

Comment: `inputColour` is a *pointer* to a `char`, not a `char` in itself. Do you know how to get characters from a string? What do you know about arrays and strings?

Comment: And using recursion instead of loops might not be a good idea.

Comment: Also, what is `database[currentStorage].colours`? Is it a single `char`? Then your `scanf` will lead to major problems, as well as the initialization of `inputColor` being wrong. Please try to create a [mre] to show us. And if your compiler doesn't emit warnings for your code, then please enable more warnings, and treat them as errors.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I tried removing the * but that does not work either.

Comment: And ***always*** check what `scanf` [*returns*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf#Return_value).

Answer (score 0):

In this if statement

```
if (inputColour == 'R') {
```

the left hand side operand `inputColour` has the pointer type `char *` due to its declaration

```
char *inputColour = database[currentStorage].colours;
```

That is you are trying to compare a pointer with a character.

You should write at least

```
if ( *inputColour == 'R') {
```

Also if the type of the expression `database[currentStorage].colours` is `char` then you have to use the conversion specifier `c` instead of `s` like

```
scanf( " %c", &database[currentStorage].colours );
```

and then

```
 char inputColour = database[currentStorage].colours;
```

Pay attention to the leading space in the format string. It allows to skip white space characters.

Otherwise you have to write

```
scanf( "%s", database[currentStorage].colours );
```

Comment: I tried this, and it works thank you! Not sure why but even after removing the * the initial if statement did not work. I will keep the * then